# Where is the read/unread field in Outlook 2010 custom search?

Tags: search, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am trying to create a custom search folder in outlook 2010. I am using the "advanced" tab in the "search folder criteria" dialog. One of the criteria I need is the read/unread status of an message. But the "field" dropdown does not contain a field corresponding to read/unread status (see screen shot below).

This is odd because the read/unread status is available in the "More Choices" tab, but seemingly not in the "advanced" tab.

How do I create an advanced search folder criteria which incorporates the read/unread status of a message?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In the "More Choices" tab the first checkbox is "only items that are" and you can choose between unread or read. This is how you filter to show only read or unread messages.

You can then apply further advanced search criteria in the Advanced tab if you wish.

Comment: This is the best answer. I didn't realise that when I select options in "More Choices" they apply _**in addition to**_ the options in "Advanced".

Comment: In my case, it only worked if I clicked "Find Now" whilst on the "More Choices" tab (after setting advanced options)

Answer (score 7):

Just type (do not try to select) "Read" for the field name and select "Yes" or "No".

Comment: This doesn't work in Professional Plus 2010.  Have you had it work?

Comment: Works in Outlook 2013

Comment: Works for me in Outlook 2010 Standard 32-bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for was possible on Outlook 2003 but not 2010. Seems to have been a step backwards by Microsoft. You can easily sort out the 'Unread' mails using the conventional **Search Folders > Unread mail** option but to get a detailed description as to why you can't sort *read* mail, look at [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-outlook/sort-and-group-inbox-contents-by-read-and-unread/61eb2456-3869-4b89-9767-aec230c0def8).

Comment: seems like a fundamental omission.

Comment: Yup, it does. Microsoft never fails to baffle. I'm using Outlook 2007 and can't figure out how to do this either.

Comment: I don't think it's a fundamental omission. They just changed the way to do this to the "More Choices" tab. I didn't previously realise that the "More Choices" options apply _**in addition to**_ those on the "Advanced" tab. See https://superuser.com/a/475939/429254

Answer (score 2):

Just found an answer for that if still relevant.

Similar to what the person above suggested, but just enter "Unread" for the field name and select "Yes" or "No".

Comment: When I try to add Unread to query builder I get an error message saying the criteria is not valid.  Read works.  This is in Outlook 2010 Standard 32-bit.

Comment: This works in 2023.

Answer (score 1):

For Office 2016 Professional:

1. in the Home tab, select the search box located above the message list
2. type `isread:yes` to filter on the read emails and type `isread:no` to filter on the unread emails.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the SQL tab if you want to use unread/read as part of a filter. This is not available directly as a Search Folder filter, but you can associate a filtered View with a search folder that has no criteria, and it will work fine.

To find out what the SQL equivalent of "unread" or "read" is, just select that criteria on the "More Choices" tab, then switch to the SQL tab. You can then combine it with other criteria with OR or AND and brackets.